# node.js sockets remembering previous state instead of current one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to write an application that waits until there are two free users, then matches them together, in order to do this I am using the following function:

```
var gameManager;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    connected_users.push(socket.id);
    console.log('user connected: ', socket.id);
    if (connected_users.length >= 2) {
        if (!gameManager) {
            var gameManager = require('./scripts/gameManager.js')();
            console.log('game started');
        }

        io.emit('initialize', gameManager.getFen());

    }
    console.log('appending event listener to user');

    socket.on('move', function(move_json) {
        console.log('move detected', move_json.player_id, gameManager)
        if(!gameManager) {
            return
        }

        // DO SOMETHING //
     });
});
```

It seems to work fine, when the second user connects immediately both games initialize (I know that right now I'm emitting the initialize to all clients, this will be changed in the future), but then the 'move' emits from the first client always fail while the ones from the second work.

That is, suppose A connected first and then B, when A does the event that triggers an emit, the log line above shows

> move detected [id of player A] undefined

while doing a move on board B gives

> move detected [id of player B] GameManager {/* all the proterties*/}

Isn't it supposed to be the same exact object? why is the first socket unable to find it while the second is working as expected?

Comment: you only make a gameManager for the 2nd connection... can you make it before anyone connects and call `.getFen()` from about the same place to get things going?

Comment: That is absolutely right.. The problem was mistakenly having 'var' in front of the creation of a new game manager.